# Add Latex font for figure labels, legends and equation annotations with .png and .eps figures

Tags: pdftex, eps, psfrag, png

For exporting `eps` figures from Matlab i use `matlabfrag` and `laprint` functions so that i split the `psfrag` commands (`.tex`) and  figure(`.eps`) streams. During the compilation using `pstool` or `auto-pst-pdf` packages, figures with `latex` text font are automatically added.

But my question is :

How to add figure labels,legends for `.png` figures similar to `psfrag`? As the `.png` is from third-party software.

Can i convert `.png` to tagged `.eps` and then add text using `psfrag` commands?

I prefer to save figures in tagged `eps` (`.eps` and `.tex`) instead of `.pdf` so that i can add latex font based on the `beamer` or `article` class used. I don't like to freeze the font of text in figures by using `PDF`.

Comment: I think [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) allows to import bitmap graphics and export them as eps+latex. But I have never used it so far.

Comment: Inkscape can do latex+pdf. just import a bitmap, trace it or leave it as is, add text and then export as pdf. A window will pop-up and lets you chose +latex. Also consider packages like `overpic` or of course `tikz` that let you overlay a picture with text.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get TeX to find text in a png the way it does for `psfrag` as essentially the information just isn't there (even if TeX could read the binary file). However if the png image has no text at all you can overlay latex text over it. there are packages to help that but you don't really need a package.

```
\includegraphics{file.png}%
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(-100,2){label 1}
\put(-100,-22){label 2}
\end{picture}
```

overlays the two labels over the image. Of course you have to judge the coordinates by eye or some external measurement.

Comment: Does Inkscape generate the picture environment as shown in your example when i add text on the png in Inkscape as suggested by Others.

Comment: No idea, i have never used inkscape:-)