# How can I add some annotations to a screenshot so that the font can fit the (La)TeX document?

Tags: diagrams

I want to add a screenshot with some text annotations in it, so that I can incorporate it into a (La)TeX document where the font used in the annotations match the document font.

What's the recommended software to create this kind of picture?

**EDIT**

This is a small example. I hope the annotations' ("Sidebar", "Title", and "Infobox") font can fit the document's. And (if possible) the annotations can come with the picture.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see how this question is related to TeX and friends... Also, you didn't specify an OS, but on Windows 7 and up, I use the Snipping Tool that can take screenshots of the whole screen, just a particular window, or an arbitrary rectangle

Comment: Under Windows 7, I use PickPick, that's pretty simple.

Comment: Do you mean so that you can incorporate it into a (La)TeX document where the font used in the annotations match the document font?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot, yes.

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily have to wrap your bitmapped image in an EPS file; Nor does the screen scapture software need to support EPS output, as you can convert other formats to EPS.

Comment: if you are using pdflatex, you do not need eps. Can just use png. As others said, any software that generate screen shot will do. If you want eps, you can convert png to eps like this: `convert file.png file.eps`

Comment: Is the text note part of the screen you want to capture, or is it something you input when capturing? More generally, maybe you could edit your question with a minimal usecase to help people understand how they can try to help you.

Comment: As per your edit to the title, maybe this question is helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Comment: Option 1. [Using `picture` environment to place annotations on `.png` figure](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60423/add-latex-font-for-figure-labels-legends-and-equation-annotations-with-png-and) option 2: [Using Tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz) Option 3: [overpic](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1452/15717) etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting the web image saved will vary with your OS.  What I did on Windows was get the webpage on the screen, hit Shft-Ctl-PrtScn.  Then I opened up MSPaint and hit Ctl-V to paste it.  Then I cropped it and saved it as LaTeXwiki.jpg.

Once I had the image, that's where LaTeX comes in.  I used `\stackinset` to overlay my comments upon the image.  In this case, I used three nested `\stackinsets` laid upon the imported graphic.  I used the left-top of the image as the origin (the `l` and `t` arguments of `\stackinset`); however, each inset could, if desired, specify its own origin (l,c,r for horizontal, t,c,b for vertical).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,xcolor,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\noindent\textcolor{red}{\sffamily\scriptsize
\stackinset{l}{3.4in}{t}{1.4in}{\stackon{\framebox(95,80){}}{Infobox}}{
\stackinset{l}{.2in}{t}{1.04in}{\stackon{\framebox(45,200){}}{Sidebar}}{
\stackinset{l}{.98in}{t}{.8in}{\framebox(30,10){} \raisebox{2pt}{Title}}{
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{LaTeXwiki}
}}}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]